# Check if an user is member of some Azure Active Directory Tenant

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

If I have an email example "abc@xyz.com". For an application that uses AAD authentication, If xyz.com is a domain for an AAD tenant, while login I will redirected to that tenant's home page. If it is gmail/outlook/yahoo I will be sent to live.com and others it will say "we could not find an account".

If I want to achieve this kind of functionality in code? checking if It is part of "some" tenant (may be not part of my subscription) or if it will be treated as live (gmail or yahoo).

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried to solve this problem?

Comment: I use the graph API to access my tenant. I can see users (search using UPN, email), applications, tenant details. Simple graph client code. I am asking about some explanation and possibility of some requirement being met (checking if user in other tenant in AAD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about Azure AD B2C, or just Azure AD? Because Azure AD does not support Google/Yahoo, etc. accounts. The "normal" Azure AD only supports LiveID as external accounts.

What you are trying to achieve is called Home-Realm Discovery and you cannot fully automate it. You can however get pretty close when you first ask your user for their e-mail address and then pass it to the Azure AD sign-in request message as [login_hint optional parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code). This will trigger the Home-Realm discovery mechanism on the Azure AD side and will do the respective actions - either redirect the user to the LiveID login page, or prompt the user for his credentials (including custom branding if configured for the users tenant).

Comment: I was talking about AAD B2B.

Comment: the answer is correct and suit your need. for login use the [common endpoint](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant/) and combine with the [login_hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code) you will get your result.