# How to check if User Exists in Azure AD B2B from email id & get its object id

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Is there a way to find out if the user exists in the Azure AD B2B and if yes, retreive its object id.

Thanks

Comment: Which one is it, B2C or B2B? Title says B2C and text + tags say B2B.

Comment: Azure AD B2B or Azure AD B2C?

Comment: sorry, its B2B.

Comment: This case may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123533/check-if-an-user-is-member-of-some-azure-active-directory-tenant