# Find out if customer has azure ad instance by email address

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

Is there a way to find out if email address belongs to Azure Ad instance?
I have a list of email addresses of my customers and I have to figure out if they have azure ad instance.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To check if the User Emails belongs to the Azure AD Tenant, you can make use of PowerShell like below:

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADUser -ObjectId User@XXX.onmicrosoft.com
```

If the User belongs to the connected Azure AD Tenant, then the user details will be retrieved otherwise it will throw an error like below:

[image]

You can also make use of the **`authorize`** endpoint to check if the user resides in the Azure AD Tenant.

For sample, when I use the below **endpoint** I get a sign-in screen.

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=user.read
&state=12345
```

When I enter the user not belonging to the Azure AD Tenant, I get the below error:

[image]

If the **User belongs to the Azure AD Tenant, then I get the redirect screen successfully** like below:

[image]

[image]

***Alternatively***, you can also make use of [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) like below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

[image]

For more in detail, **refer** below links:

[Verify if user account exists in Azure Active Directory by  Rohit Saigal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58380915/verify-if-user-account-exists-in-azure-active-directory)

[Check if an user is member of some Azure Active Directory Tenant by astaykov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123533/check-if-an-user-is-member-of-some-azure-active-directory-tenant)